# How to copy a file in one directory and move it to the other?

Tags: unix, terminal, cp, mv

So, I am currently in my lab6 folder. In that folder, I have a makefile that is very similar to the one I need in lab7. So, I just want to copy that makefile in lab6 and move it to lab7. My current directory is

username:~/fall2016/csc111/labs/lab6

How would I do so?

Comment: You're asking how to copy a file?

Comment: @CareyGregory ..yes

Comment: Wrong forum. YOu need to delete this and post it on superuser. It will be closed here.

Comment: @careyGregory why so?

Comment: You need to read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and learn what is on topic here. Stackoverflow is for programming questions, and how to copy a file isn't a programming question (the fact that it's a makefile isn't relevant -- it's just a file). This question is exactly what Superuser is for and that's where it should have been posted. Even if nobody pays enough attention to close this question, it has already earned you and the answers downvotes, and that's why.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks for all the intel! I'll be soon to jump right on that!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the basic copy "cp" command.
Use this command on your "lab6" directory:

> cp makefile /path/to/lab7/directory/

for example:

> cp makefile ~/fall2016/csc111/labs/lab7/

If this folder and file need root permission, use sudo in front of your command, i.e:

> sudo cp makefile /path/to/lab7/directory/

Enter your sudo password.
I hope this will answer you question.

Answer (score -1):

First off, read this, it is very helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_(Unix)

Now for an answer to your question.

Presuming your lab7 file is also in labs:

`cp yourfile.something ../lab7/renameifyouwant.something`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!